# WMI Performance counter Query issues

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, performancecounter

Is there a way to query via WMI in C# like you can do with the `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` class?

Simply put how can I pass it a string like `\\localhost\Processor(0)\% Processor Time` and it would build the correct WMI query for me?

I have huge list of counters in a flat file from a legacy program and I want to move it to a Service which just runs through the flat file and gets the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WMI [Performance Class Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392738(v=VS.85).aspx). An example of this would be polling the PerfDisk_LogicalDisk

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk");
foreach (ManagementObject service in mos.Get())
{
    foreach (PropertyData data in service.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", data.Name, data.Value);
    }
}
```